# How do I do CRUD jobs using pdo?

Tags: php, pdo

Where is a hello world example that has all CRUD operations included?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get your answer after reading this great [tutorial about PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? [PDO CRUD Tutorial](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2012/02/pdo-crud-tutorial.html), hope this helps someone.